# How to embed client certificate into react native iOS app

Tags: react-native, nsurlsession, client-certificates, sslpinning, ios-app-signing

I am developing a React Native app for Android & iOS both.
I want to embed the client certificate into my React Native app. I have Cloudflare's client certificate in pem format & its private key in pem format.
My server has rules enabled so API calls with valid certificates can only work.

I have successfully implemented Android. and my API calls are working for Android.
But for iOS, I am still not able to do it. The embedding certificate with the `URLSession` part is left.

My React native app uses `axios` library for API calls. how can I also embed the certificate with my app to work for iOS?

I have done some implementation & tried calling API directly using `NSURLSession`. So my request is getting success. I am getting 200 response. That means I am successfully able to import certificate data.

> My `MyURLSessionDelegate` file is in Swift & my `AppDelegate` code is in Objective C++. I have done bridging.

Here is the code:

*MyURLSessionDelegate.swift*

```
import Foundation

public class MyURLSessionDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
             != NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {
                completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
                return
        }

              guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CERTIFICATE-NAME“, withExtension: "p12"),
              let p12Data = try? Data(contentsOf: file) else {
            // Loading of the p12 file's data failed.
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            return
        }

        let password = "password" // Obviously this should be stored or entered more securely.
        let p12Contents = PKCS12(pkcs12Data: p12Data, password: password)
        guard let identity = p12Contents.identity else {
            // Creating a PKCS12 never fails, but interpretting th contained data can. So again, no identity? We fall back to default.
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            return
        }

        let credential = URLCredential(identity: identity,
                                   certificates: nil,
                                    persistence: .none)
        challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
}

private class PKCS12 {
    let label: String?
    let keyID: NSData?
    let trust: SecTrust?
    let certChain: [SecTrust]?
    let identity: SecIdentity?

    public init(pkcs12Data: Data, password: String) {
        let importPasswordOption: NSDictionary
          = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString: password]
        var items: CFArray?
        let secError: OSStatus
          = SecPKCS12Import(pkcs12Data as NSData,
                            importPasswordOption, &items)
        guard secError == errSecSuccess else {
            if secError == errSecAuthFailed {
                NSLog("Incorrect password?")

            }
            fatalError("Error trying to import PKCS12 data")
        }
        guard let theItemsCFArray = items else { fatalError() }
        let theItemsNSArray: NSArray = theItemsCFArray as NSArray
        guard let dictArray
          = theItemsNSArray as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
            fatalError()
          }
        func f<T>(key: CFString) -> T? {
            for dict in dictArray {
                if let value = dict[key as String] as? T {
                    return value
                }
              }
            return nil
        }
        self.label = f(key: kSecImportItemLabel)
        self.keyID = f(key: kSecImportItemKeyID)
        self.trust = f(key: kSecImportItemTrust)
        self.certChain = f(key: kSecImportItemCertChain)
        self.identity = f(key: kSecImportItemIdentity)

    }
}
```

*AppDelegate.mm*

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <TrustKit/TrustKit.h>
#import “MyApp-Swift.h" // Import the Swift module header


@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
  
  [FIRApp configure];
  self.moduleName = @"MyApp”;
  self.initialProps = @{};

    MyURLSessionDelegate *myURLSessionDelegate = [[MyURLSessionDelegate alloc] init];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:myURLSessionDelegate delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.example.com/rest/login"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // Set the parameters
    NSDictionary *params = @{
        @"username": @“User123”,
        @"password": @“User@123”
    };

    // Convert parameters to data
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        request.HTTPBody = postData;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error encoding parameters: %@", error);
    }

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Handle response or error here
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            return;
        }

        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            NSLog(@"Response status code: %ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Invalid response");
            return;
        }

        if (data) {
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];

  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}

@end
```